# What statistical test should be used to test the relationship between the variables for a non-linear data set?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonlinear-regression

I am currently conducting an experiment and I am struggling to find a statistical test to test the relationship between my independent and dependent variables. My research is to find the relationship between [IV] increasing concentrations of metal ions and the [DV] chlorophyll content in the leaves of a plant. My supervisor has told me to use a repeated measures ANOVA, but my understanding was that ANOVA tests were only used to find the statistical significance between datapoints and not the relationship between the variables (although I may be wrong here). My graph is non-linear and looks something like the plot below:[image]

Where the y-axis is the concentration of metal ions and the x-axis is the total chlorophyll content. I was thinking of drawing two lines (one from 0 to 5, the other from 5 to 25) and finding the Pearson's correlation coefficient of both lines or conducting a Spearman's Rank. Which test would be better? Additionally, I would like to find the significant differences between the datasets, so which test should I follow up with? ANOVA, or any other test? Thank you!

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Cross Validated. Some thoughts: a) do you need a statistical test and if so, what is your hypothesis? If you can plot a curve, an empirical result may be fine. b) Related... do you have a theoretical prediction (e.g. a quadratic form where chlorophyll increases up to some point, then decreases) - if so, you could fit a model of that form and see if the data aligns. c) I'd suggest plotting chlorophyll on the y and ion content on the x, as this is more a standard and interpretable way of visualising data. d) a really general way to fit non-linear relationships smoothing e.g. GAM

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What are you doing to get those $\text X$s and intervals around them? What are you doing to generate the curve? // Do you even have repeated measures for which you could perform a repeated-measures ANOVA? You might, but that is not obvious from your graph.